# Reset the values of variables in docplex - Python

Tags: python, docplex

I have a mathematical model ('mdl'), and I want to solve it in an iterative manner using the docplex library in python, like the below simplified example:

```
mdl = Model("LTC")
x = mdl.binary_var_dict(set_idx1, name="x")
#model defined here
for i in range(0, 5):
    solution = mdl.solve()
```

For each iteration, I want to reset the values of the variable in order to ensure that each run does not start with an initial solution (from the previous iteration). How can I achieve this aim? Thanks. Does adding 'mdl.clear_mip_starts()' help (like below)?

```
mdl = Model("LTC")
x = mdl.binary_var_dict(set_idx1, name="x")
#model defined here
for i in range(0, 5):
    solution = mdl.solve()
    mdl.clear_mip_starts()
```

Or I should clear each variable one by one like below?

```
mdl = Model("LTC")
x = mdl.binary_var_dict(set_idx1, name="x")
#model defined here
for i in range(0, 5):
    solution = mdl.solve()
    x.clear()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default, a `Model` instance "remembers" the details of the last solve, reusing the last solution as a MIP start for the next solve.

If you want to start a fresh solve, simply add the `clean_before_solve=True` keyword argument to `Model.solve()`, as in

m`.solve(clean_before_solve=True, log_output=True)`

You should not see any reference to MIP starts in the log.
and btw, there is no "reset" method on variable containers (lists or dicts).

To answer your question, `Model.clear_mip_starts` clears only mip starts that *you* entered, not those from the solve history. Actually, solve remembers more than mip starts, so the right way to start a fresh solve is `clean_before_solve`